# How to set cursor of combox to a specific index?

Tags: java, algorithm, apache-flex, flex3, flex4.5

```
<code>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:HGroup xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
          xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
          xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
          creationComplete="init()">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Script>

            <![CDATA[
                import com.amdocs.infra.utils.FlexFormatters;

                import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
                import mx.controls.DateField;
                import mx.events.CalendarLayoutChangeEvent;
                import mx.events.FlexEvent;
                import mx.formatters.DateFormatter;
                import mx.utils.StringUtil;

                import spark.events.IndexChangeEvent;
                private  var arr:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
                private var date:Date;
                private var selecteDate:Date = new Date();
                public var dateChanged :Boolean;
                [Bindable]
                private var timezone:String;


                [Bindable]
                public function get selectedDate():Date 
                {
                    if(dateChanged)
                    return date;
                    else
                        return selecteDate;
                }

                public function set selectedDate(value:Date):void
                {
                    if(value.toString()!= null)
                    {
                    selecteDate = value;
                    var dateformatter:DateFormatter = new DateFormatter();
                    dateformatter.formatString = "MM/DD/YYYY L:NN:SSA";
                    var dateStr:String = dateformatter.format(value).substr(0,10);
                    var dateArray:Array = dateStr.split("/");
                    dateInput.selectedDate = new Date(dateArray[2],dateArray[0]-1,dateArray[1]);
                    timeInput.selectedItem =  dateformatter.format(value).substr(11,10);
                    dateStringLabel.text = FlexFormatters.getDateTimeFormatter({ dateTimePattern: "EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm:ss a" }).format(value);
                    dateChanged = false;    
                    timezone = TimeZoneUtil.getTimeZone();

                    }
                }

            protected function formatTime():void
            {
             var rawTimeString:String;
            // If the combobox has a custom value, hten use the selectedItem.  Otherwise, use the selectedItem.value
             if (timeInput.selectedIndex == ComboBox.CUSTOM_SELECTED_ITEM)
             rawTimeString = StringUtil.trim(timeInput.selectedItem).toUpperCase();
             else if (timeInput.selectedIndex != -1)
             rawTimeString = StringUtil.trim(timeInput.selectedItem).toUpperCase();

            // look for AM or PM at end of the timestring
            var amPm:String = "";
            if (rawTimeString.substr(-2) == "AM" )
            amPm = "AM";
            else if (rawTimeString.substr(-2) == "PM" )
            amPm = "PM";

            // Split time by colons
            var timeArr:Array = StringUtil.trimArrayElements(rawTimeString.replace(amPm, ""),":").split(":");
            var hour:int = 0;
            var minute:int = 0;
            var second:int = 0;

            // determine the hour/minute/second from the array
            if (timeArr.length >= 2)
            {
                hour = timeArr[0];
                minute = timeArr[1];
                second = (timeArr.length == 3 ? timeArr[2] : 0) ;
            }
            else
            {
            trace("Error parsing time (" + rawTimeString + ").  Defaulting to midnight");
            }

            // If it is an AM time and hour is 12 (midnight) then set the hour to zero)
            if (amPm == "AM" && hour == 12)
                hour = 0;
            // add 12 hours if the hour is between 1 and 11
            else if (amPm == "PM" && hour >=1 && hour <= 11)
                hour = hour + 12;

            // If hours, minutes, or seconds exceed what they should be, then
            // calculate how many days/hours/minutes should be added to the final date 
            // and determine the final hour/minute/second
            if (second >= 60)
            {
                minute += Math.floor(second/60);
                second = second % 60;
            }
            if (minute >= 60)
            {
                hour += Math.floor(minute/60);
                minute = minute % 60;
            }
            var addedDays:int = 0;
            if (hour >= 24)
            {
                addedDays += Math.floor(hour/24);
                hour = hour % 24;
            }                 
            var timeString:String = lpad(hour,2,"0") + ":" + lpad(minute,2,"0") + ":" + lpad(second,2,"0");
            var dateString:String = FlexFormatters.getDateTimeFormatter({ "dateTimePattern": "yyyy-MM-dd" }).format(dateInput.selectedDate);

            // Create date from final dateString/timeString
            date = DateFormatter.parseDateString(dateString + " " + timeString);

            // Add days to the final date if needed
            if (date != null && addedDays > 0)
            date.setDate(date.getDate() + addedDays);

            //dateValueLabel.text = (date != null?date.toString():null);
            dateStringLabel.text = FlexFormatters.getDateTimeFormatter({ dateTimePattern: "EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm:ss a" }).format(date);
            dateChanged = true;
            }

            // helper function to add a leading zero to hour/minute/second
            private function lpad(number:int, width:int, padChar:String = " "):String 
            { 
                var ret:String = ""+number; 
                while( ret.length < width ) 
                ret=padChar + ret; 
                return ret; 
            }
            private function init():void 
            {
            for each (var ampm : String in ["AM","PM"])
                {
                for(var i :int = 0;i<12;i++)
                {
                    var hours:int = (i == 0?12:i);
                    for each(var minutes : String in ["00","30"])
                            {
                                var item:Object = hours+":"+minutes+" "+ampm;
                                arr.addItem(item);


                                //trace(hours+":"+minutes+" "+ampm);
                            }
                        }
                    }                 
                    timeInput.dataProvider = arr;

                }       

                protected function timeInput_changeHandler(event:IndexChangeEvent):void
                {
                    if (timeInput.selectedIndex!= ComboBox.CUSTOM_SELECTED_ITEM)
                    {

                        timeInput.selectedItem = String(timeInput.selectedItem).replace(" ",":00");
                    }
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if(dateInput.selectedDate!= null)

                        formatTime();



                }

                protected function dateInput_changeHandler(event:CalendarLayoutChangeEvent):void
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if(timeInput.selectedItem!= null)
                    formatTime();
            }


            ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
<s:VGroup>
        <s:HGroup>
            <mx:DateField id="dateInput"  change="dateInput_changeHandler(event)"/>
            <s:ComboBox id="timeInput"  labelField="value" initialize="timeInput_initializeHandler(event)" click="timeInput_clickHandler(event)" change="timeInput_changeHandler(event)"/>
            <s:Label text="{timezone}" paddingTop="8"/>
        </s:HGroup>
    <s:Label id="dateStringLabel"/>
 </s:VGroup>
</s:HGroup>
</code>
```

Above code is a Date Time Picker in which user can choose any date and time in (HH:MM:SSAM/PM) format.

This Date time selector will be called when user double click on a Grid.In a grid there is column called Selected Date.The value which bring from beckend is Breaked up in to date and time differenlty and assigned to datefield and time to combox.

Client wants to combox work in following way :

Suppose if Selected Date field is 12/12/12 4:20:15 AM and if user click on Drop Down then Drop down should not start from 12:00 AM everytime it should start from it nearest upcoming time like for time 4:20:15 AM it should be start from 4:30:00 AM for 7:50:12 AM it should be start from 8:00 AM 
Please Advice

Answer (score 0):

So you have some data in timeInput.dataProvider, so I think the clean solution would be just to find the wanted item in this dataProvider (say the value with "4:30") and then just set it as selectedItem (or index to selectedIndex), this will make the dropdown scrolled to this item when opened.

You could just scroll manually (programatically) the dropdown on an event, but its little more work, maybe would have to also create custom combobox (I would have to try myself to say), but still I ould call this "less clean" solution to add this feature...

Comment: No,the issue is in combox value should be displayed as 4:20:15 AM but when user want to select any value from combox it should be start from 4:30.Supoose if value is 9:45 PM then it should be start from 10:00 PM

Comment: i have written some logic but first thing is I did nt see how i can progatmically scroll the bar and second on which event will i call it on changes its not working

Comment: There was a method list.scrollToIndex() in list component, but it was for sure in mx:List, I am not so sure if it is in spark version s:List. Still, this can be done "manually", I would overide the combobox and create my own functionality there. I am sorry I cannot try (code) it myself right now and say exact steps...

Comment: Oh, in spark, that method is called differently: ensureIndexIsVisible()